# Recursive Query in MySQL using stored proceedure and CURSOR

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, tree, cursor, recursive-query

I'm expanding our user/group system to allow for dynamic groups which are made up of other groups members.  I have three tables `users`, `groups`, and `relationships`.

For simplicity sake, lets say **users** only contains one field `user_id`, and **groups** only contains `group_id`.  `relationships` uses three fields: `user_id`, `group_id`, `related_group_id` to represent both **user to group** and **group to group** relationships.

A dynamically populated group hierarchy would be something like:

Users `A, B, C` belong to Group `1` and Users `D, E, F` belong to Group 2. All of these are represented in the **relationships** table as (`user_id`,`group_id`):

```
A,1
B,1
C,1
D,2
E,2
F,2
```

The dynamic Group `3` would have two **group to group** relationship records (`group_id`,`related_group_id`):

```
3,1
3,2
```

To illustrate my problem better lets add a Dynamic Group `4` and have it include Group `3`:

```
4,3
```

Piecing together what I've learned of MySQL `CURSOR`'s, I've created the following stored procedure called `fetch_inheritance_groups`:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `fetch_inheritance_groups`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `fetch_inheritance_groups`(IN parent_id INT)
    READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN

    DECLARE inherit_id char(32);
    DECLARE eol BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE inherit_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT r.Related_Group_ID FROM usr_relationships r WHERE r.Group_ID = parent_id AND r.Related_Group_ID IS NOT NULL;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET eol = TRUE;

    OPEN inherit_cur;
    inherited: LOOP
        FETCH inherit_cur INTO inherit_id;

        IF eol 
            THEN
            CLOSE inherit_cur;
            LEAVE inherited;
        ELSE
            CALL fetch_inheritance_groups(inherit_id);
        END IF;

        SELECT inherit_id;

    END LOOP inherited;

END;
```

...which is called with...

```
CALL fetch_inheritance_groups(4);
```

...and returns the expected results of

```
3
2
1
```

Herein begins my problem, they're returned as three separate result sets rather than three rows in a single result set, and secondly, the results are meant to be used within a query like:

```
SELECT r.uer_id FROM relationships r WHERE r.group_id = 4 OR r.group_id IN (CALL fetch_inheritance_groups(4));
```

So the three questions I'm hoping someone can answer are:

**1. Should I be using a `CURSOR` here or is there an alternative that will get the same recursive result?**

**2. How can I get the results back in a single result set so that it can be used in the same fashion as a subselect?**

**3. What is the proper way of using the results from the `CALL` because I can't at least as far as I've tried get the sample SELECT statement above to work?  I believe this is because I can't use `CALL` inline but I'm not sure.**